# How to refresh data in Recycleview adaper after deleting a row in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have used a Recycleview using cardivew with list of data and button to delete any value. when I click button it does delete the value from firebase database but still the text and row remains in adapter in app but only when i close activity by going back and reopen then row is empty.

I used below method at two places each time ( I have shown in code also ) but it doesn't work

```
                         bookslist.remove(position);   
                         notifyDataSetChanged();
```

How can I update the recycleview instantly when I hit delete button

Here is my code

```html
public class SubjectBooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectBooksAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Books> bookslist;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference dbreference;


    public SubjectBooksAdapter(ArrayList<Books> bookslist){
        this.bookslist = bookslist;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);



    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   
          Button mSolved;
 




        MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
 
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            dbreference = database.getReference("roomrequest");
             dbreference.keepSynced(true);

            mSolved = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_solved);
            mSolved.setTransformationMethod(null);


            fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbreference = database.getReference("roomrequest");
        
   
        holder.mSolved.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               



                    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    DatabaseReference classicalMechanicsRef = rootRef.child("roomrequest").child("request").child(g.getRequestid());
                    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                             bookslist.remove(position);   \\ Solution One
                             notifyDataSetChanged();       \\ Solution One
                    
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    };
                    classicalMechanicsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
                             bookslist.remove(position);   \\ Solution Two
                             notifyDataSetChanged();       \\ Solution Two
                    
                }
            
        });



 }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookslist.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you simply tried to use `classicalMechanicsRef.removeValue()` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged();` without attaching a listener? Does it work this way?

Comment: Ok I'll try and update you.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: @AlexMamo nope it doesn't do anything ..it does deletes the row but rows stays as it is unless I press back and finish activity and reopen activity again.

Answer (score 0):

use `notifyItemRemoved(position);`

E.g. -

```
bookslist.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Comment: sorry it didn't work either.when I press button it is still there ..only when I exit activity and reopen it then row is empty or gone.